# inserting record in two table within one transaction block in same method

Tags: mysql, transactions, spring-transactions

I want to insert/update records in two tables within one transaction in same method.

first insert into table1 and if that is successful then update the table2 and then if both  are successful then only commit otherwise dont commit (in both table)

my code is like below:

```
@Transactional
public void persistTable1AndTable2() {
    persistTable1(List<Table1Entity>);
    updateTable2(List<Table2Entity>);
}
```

however when I test the code, and if after persistTable1 line I terminate the process, it still insert the record in first table.
so it doesnt consider this as block transaction.

I am using mysql.

Just to add: 
above both table1 and table2 uses separate transactionmanager and entityManagerFactory

Can someone please help

[EDIT]

Code to configure JTA using atomikos API.

```
//Atomikos related JTA configuration
@Bean(name="userTransactionServiceImp")
public UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp()
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout", "600000");
    UserTransactionServiceImp userTransactionServiceImp = new UserTransactionServiceImp(properties);
    return userTransactionServiceImp;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
public UserTransaction userTransaction()
{
    UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
    return userTransactionImp;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("userTransactionServiceImp")
public TransactionManager userTransactionManager()
{
    UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
    userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
    userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
    return userTransactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
{
    return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction(), userTransactionManager());
}
```

and configure jparepo I am having below config class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"daemon.repository.entities"}, 
    transactionManagerRef="transactionManager", entityManagerFactoryRef = "eventsEntityMF")
```

Comment: Are those tables in the same DB?

Comment: No, they are in two different DB. Table1 in DB1 and Table2 in DB2. I have configured entityManager and TransactionManager in Java class. and both entityManager and TransactionManager are different for both entity.

I have edited my post with the code I am trying with JTA.

Comment: Then you just need to use JTA for this task.

Comment: I just added the code that I am using for JTA config however that is not working...

Comment: I haven't used Atomikos. Maybe you should ask this question on the Spring forum.

Comment: so what if I dont use atomikos.... ? how else I can configure JTA in java class... any suggestion.

Comment: I have this [example on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/transaction/spring/jta/config/JTATransactionManagerConfiguration.java) which uses Bitronix and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example of something similar here

Have a quick check http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

See if you are missing some configuration

Comment: I used the link mentioned above by @Rajinder and was able to successfully  config JTA after some tweeks. I had to set maxPoolSize because I was getting poolsize related error. also set classDriver which is missing in the link above. 
Thanks